# how to configure http uri healthcheck for a ws balancer with Apache Httpd

Tags: apache, websocket, load-balancing, health-check

i need to configure healthcheck for my ws load balancer within Apache httpd.
i am using mod_proxy_wstunnel for websocket tunneling and mod_balancer for load balancing between 2 servers. 
i am using additionnaly mod_proxy_hcheck for verifying if the 2 servers are available.
the configuration is following:

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
ProxyHCExpr ok2 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[2]/}
    <Proxy balancer://trackingwsbalancer>
    BalancerMember  wss://{{ rpa_fqdn_tracking1 }}:8443 route=1 hcmethod=GET hcexpr=ok2 hcuri=/trackingproxy_advanced/actuator
    BalancerMember  wss://{{ rpa_fqdn_tracking2 }}:8443 route=2 hcmethod=GET hcexpr=ok2 hcuri=/trackingproxy_advanced/actuator
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    </Proxy>
```

the problem is that the healthcheck always fails because the request behind is:

```
wss ://{{ rpa_fqdn_tracking1 }}:8443/trackingproxy_advanced/actuator.
```

and i want it to be

```
htpps ://{{ rpa_fqdn_tracking1 }}:8443/trackingproxy_advanced/actuator
```

in order to be able to handle the response for healthcheck correctly with hcexpr

i will greatly appreciate any idea to configure the protocole for the uri healthcheck.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the mod_proxy_hcheck  module says that it performs a HTTP request. 
 After inspecting the mod_proxy_hcheck.c( Apche 2.4.39), it seems that this case is not covered. The code doesn't check if the scheme is ws and does not replace it when it create the request.

It should be great to be able to add an absolute uri for the hckeck or replace automatically the protocol used if it's not http.